# What is complexity of cons operator in Scala/OCaml?

Tags: scala, time-complexity, ocaml

What is complexity of these codes?

I have written the following code:

```ml
let rec replicate (element, reps) = 
    if reps < 0 then failwith "Negative reps"
    else if reps = 0 then []
    else element :: replicate (element, reps - 1);;
```

```scala
def replicate[A](element:A, reps:Int):List[A] = 
if (reps < 0) throw new Exception("Negative reps")
else if (reps == 0) Nil
else element :: replicate(element, reps-1)
```

I wonder especially what is complexity of cons operator (::).

Comment: I can not talk about **OCaml** _(but I suppose it should be the same as in **Scala** / **Haskell**)_. But in **Scala**, the complexity of `::` is **O(1)** due structural sharing, like it does not copy all the previous elements of the list, it just creates a new list with a new head and the tail is the previous list. Thus, the overall complexity of the algorithm is **O(N)** _(where `N` is `reps`)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cons is `O(1)` so these codes are `O(n)`.

However this code is inefficient because it does not use tail recursion and therefore cannot be optimised into a loop (or at least using tail call elimination).

Something like this is better (for Scala)

```
def replicate[A](element: A, reps: Int): List[A] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(rem: Int, res: List[A]): List[A] =
    if (rem <= 0) {
      res
    } else {
      loop(rem - 1, element :: res)
    }

  if (reps < 0) {
    throw new Exception("Negative reps")
  } else {
    loop(reps, Nil)
  }
}
```

This is optimised to a loop by Scala, and also avoids testing the error condition every iteration.

Of course in Scala it is easier just to use

```
List.fill(reps)(element)
```

Comment: This answer is correct. I would also like to add that `::` in Scala is nothing special: it is just a method, and you can lookup its implementation. It is simply creating a new `Cons` object that packs the `head` and `tail` of the `List`, without any more complex operation. The only thing that makes it special is that the method name starts with `:`, which in Scala means that it is applied on the right, so `1 :: 2 :: Nil` gets translated to `Nil.::(2.::(1))`.

Comment: Note: the answer is totally applicable to OCaml (modulo syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Answering from the future: as of OCaml 4.14 (and later, released 2022) there is `tail_mod_cons` which makes it trivial to implement this using tail recursion while remaining O(n).

```ml
let[@tail_mod_cons] rec replicate (element, reps) = 
  if reps < 0 then failwith "Negative reps"
  else if reps = 0 then []
  else element :: replicate (element, reps - 1)
```

Though OCaml would typically use currying rather than passing a tuple.

```ml
let[@tail_mod_cons] rec replicate element reps = 
  if reps < 0 then failwith "Negative reps"
  else if reps = 0 then []
  else element :: replicate element (reps - 1)
```

And this is really just a specialization of `List.init`.

```ml
let replicate element reps =
  try
    List.init reps @@ Fun.const element
  with
  | Invalid_argument _ -> failwith "Negative reps"
```